# Request HTTP every 1 sec and update state with the incoming object from the response delays the application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, timing

I need to request an endpoint every 1 sec and with that response (around 30 array) update React context state and the ui. It's working but at some point it got so slow and chrome start behaving weird. What is the best way to solve this? with some library like lodash?

Hook/context state:

```
const [stateData, setStateData] = useState(null);
```

The following method is the one that triggers every X sec, where X can be [1,10,15,20] seconds

```
  const subscribeOb = async (): Promise<void> => {
    await m?.subscribe((event) => {
     getData()
   });
  };
```

This method is the one that its called once the subscription triggered

```
  const getData = async (): Promise<void> => {
  try {
   const { a, b } = await generalObj?.data();
   const currentA = (stateData?.asks as Data[]) || [];
   const currentB = (stateData?.bids as Data[]) || [];
   const newObj = {
     asks: [...a, ...currentA],
     bids: [...b, ...currentB],
   };
   setStateData(newObj); // this is from the hook in the context
  } catch (e) {
  console.log("Error found while getting Data", e);
  }
};
```

Comment: Hey. You better post your code or a picture of it so that people can help you better. This is really confusing my friend.

Comment: is there a reason why you aren't using a WebSocket connection?

Comment: @Noah yes, this is a big picture of a smart contract implementation. I thought about the ws connection but not sure if can work for us